# how to display name field rather than id field in view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display the CategoryName in my view page but it is showing only the CategoryId which I inserted from dropdown. Can you please look on my code and help me? What do I need to do for displaying CategoryName instead of CategoryId??

Thank you in advance.

Following are my codes:

ProductController.cs

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ProductBusinessLayer productBusinessLayer = new ProductBusinessLayer();
            List<Product> products = productBusinessLayer.Products.ToList();
            return View(products);
        }
```

ProductBusinessLayer.cs

```
 public IEnumerable<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                string connectionString =
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCSS"].ConnectionString;

                List<Product> productList = new List<Product>();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllProducts", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Product products = new Product();
                        products.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ProductID"]);
                        products.CategoryId = rdr["CategoryId"].ToString();

                        productList.Add(products);
                    }
                }

                return productList;
            }
        }
```

Product.cs

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryId)
```

Category.cs

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Categories
        {
            get
            {
                string connectionString =
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCSS"].ConnectionString;

                List<Category> categoryList = new List<Category>();

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetAllCategory", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        Category categories = new Category();
                        categories.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CategoryId"]);
                        categories.CategoryName = rdr["CategoryName"].ToString();                                             categoryList.Add(categories);
                    }
                }

                return categoryList;
            }
        }
```